# VM can't ping the host in VirtualBox host-only networking

Tags: virtualbox, ping

My host is MAC OS. In Virtualbox, I create a host-only network whose name is "vboxnet0", where adapter IPv4 address is 192.168.56.1/24, IPv6 disabled and DHCP server disabled.

I have a ubuntu server VM. I enable 2 network adapters for the VM. Adapter1 uses NAT with eth0, Adapter2 uses host-only network "vboxnet0" with eth1. In /etc/network/interfaces, I added the following commands:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.56.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

From the host, I can ping the VM; However I can't ping from VM to the host.

Host's routing table

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGSc           38        0     en1
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              9   169482     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.0          link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.0.1/32     link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
192.168.0.1        84:94:8c:91:1a:f2  UHLWIir        40       25     en1   1194
192.168.0.15/32    link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.56         link#11            UC              2        0 vboxnet
192.168.56.1       a:0:27:0:0:0       UHLWIi          1       76     lo0
192.168.56.50      8:0:27:9d:5:77     UHLWI           0        5 vboxnet   1084
```

VM's routing table:

```
Destination        Gateway      Genmask         Flags   Metric   Ref Use Iface
default            10.0.2.2     0.0.0.0         UG       0       0    0  eth0
10.0.2.0           *            255.255.255.0   U        0       0    0  eth0
192.168.56.0       *            255.255.255.0   U        0       0    0  eth1
```

VM's arp table:

```
Address            HWtype     HWaddress         Flags Mask    Iface
192.168.56.1       ether      0a:00:27:00:00:00  C             eth1
10.0.2.2           ether      52:54:00:12:35:02  C             eth0
```

192.168.56.1's mac address is the same as the configuration on the host. This info means ARP works.

Start wireshark to listen to the interface "vboxnet0" on the host, I can see ARP received and ICMPs received on the host. ICMP packet says:"Expert Info (Warn/Sequence): No response seen to ICMP request in frame 14" (I can't put the screenshot because of lack of reputation)

Answer (score 2):

**Firewall settings.**
(I know this is an old question, but I hope this will help anyone reading)

I'm not sure about the firewall setting on MAC OS. But on Windows 10, when `I can't ping from a Host to VM but can ping from VM to Host`. This is caused by Outbound Firewall rule.

If you don't know which part of which device's firewall to configure, start by disabling the whole thing and go from there.